# Given an Applications Insight Instrumentation key, get the name of the service in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

How can I programmatically determine the name of the Application Insights instance given the instrumentation key?

Our company has a large number of application insights instances in Azure. When troubleshooting an application, it can take quite a while to track down the right app insights instance for a particular app.

> I should have specified (more than just using C# tag), that I was looking for a C# solution. Ideally, I would like to embed something so I could implement a page like 'myapp.com/appinsights' and this would give me the correct app insights instance (of the hundreds that we have) for a given app.

Comment: you could just put them in a spreadsheet. How are you managing governence?

Comment: He he... There is a spreadsheet. but it gets reliably updated at the same rate as every other such spreadsheet. I.e. Almost never. Ideally I would have couple lines of c# and the app could simply have a url to report the name or maybe even direct me right to the proper link on the portal

Comment: @johnweeder did you ever get a C# implementation of this?

Comment: No I didn't get anything

Comment: Anyone looking at these answers should know all the `AzureRM` powershell commandlets are now deprecated and you should use the `Az` equivalents now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using PowerShell with the AzureRm cmdlets. If you are new to that, take a look here at the [Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/).

You'll first need to login with `Login-AzureRmAccount` and then select a subscription with `Select-AzureRmSubscription`

The following script will get a list of the name of each Application Insights instance and its instrumentationkey:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ExpandProperties -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components"  -ResourceGroupName "your-resource-group" | select -ExpandProperty Properties  | Select Name, InstrumentationKey
```

This works as follows:

1. Get all resources of type microsoft.insight/components from within your group
2. Expand the properties of it
3. Find the instrumentationkey and name in the properties

Comment: If you want to search across all resource groups, this works

Find-AzureRmResource -ExpandProperties -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components" | select -ExpandProperty Properties  | Select Name, InstrumentationKey

Comment: IMHO @mafue's answer in the comment should be promoted to a full fledged answer and voted up.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree this works and it is a useful approach. My goal (which I did not specify well... shame on me as a programmer) was a C# solution that I could embed within an application. However, since no one has supplied a C# solution, I'm gonna select this answer since it is useful in and of itself.

Comment: This solution is out of date.  See kayjtea's answer below to use az commands.

Answer (score 23):

The older `AzureRM` PowerShell module [is being replaced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az) by the new cross-platform `Az` module. Based on the answers of @tobias and @ranieuwe, the following can fetch all your InstrumentationKeys using the newer module.

#### Install the `Az` module

`Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber` as admin, or

`Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser` as non-admin

Full instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps

#### Remove older AzureRM module if needed

If you get warnings about both `Az` and `AzureRM` being installed/loaded, you can uninstall the old module by [running the following as admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps): `Uninstall-AzureRm`

#### Login to Azure and select Instrumentation Keys

```bsh
Import-Module Az
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzSubscription # will list all currently connected subscriptions
Select-AzSubscription <subscription-id>

# Retrieve all Instrumentation Keys along with name of AppInsights resource
Get-AzResource -ExpandProperties -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components" | Select -ExpandProperty Properties | Select Name, InstrumentationKey

# Find a specific Instrumentation Key
Get-AzResource -ExpandProperties -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components" | Select -ExpandProperty Properties | Where InstrumentationKey -eq "abe66a40-c437-4af1-bfe9-4b72bd6b94a1"| Select Name, InstrumentationKey
```

Comment: Thanks, in my script I added these lines so I could assign the subscription id based on the subscription name (or name fragment... I assume you'll get the first if you have more than one match?)

$subscriptionName = "[subscription-name-fragment]"
$subscriptionId = (Get-AzSubscription | Where Name -like *$subscriptionName*).Id

Answer (score 21):

Using azure cloud shell (or any shell where you have azure-cli ^2.0.64 installed):

```
az extension add --name application-insights
az monitor app-insights component show --output table | grep <instrumentation_key>
```

This searches across your current subscription. You can see your current subscription with

```
az account show
```

There are probably fancier ways to use --query but the above approach is general purpose.

Comment: This is a great solution using commonly installed windows tools.  Minor change for Windows users changing grep to findstr:
az monitor app-insights component show --output table | findstr <instrumentation_key>

Comment: Result: `No matching extensions for 'application-insights'. Use --debug for more information.`

Comment: `Select-String -Pattern '<instrumentation-key>'` can be used when calling Azure CLI from PowerShell.

Comment: Amazing! FYI, didn't even need first line - just run second line and CLI asks if you want to add that extension? Lovely stuff :)

Answer (score 10):

This is quite simple using the azure CLI:

```
az monitor app-insights component show --query "[?instrumentationKey=='471b5965-ce0a-4718-9bce-dc4dbcb4255f'].[applicationId, instrumentationKey]"
```

or you can list all of your app insights instances out using:

```
az monitor app-insights component show --query "[].[applicationId, instrumentationKey]"
```

Answer (score 3):

As per @mafue's comment, the following powershell commands let you find instrumentation keys across resource groups:

```bsh
Import-Module -Name AzureRM
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription <subscription id> 

Find-AzureRmResource -ExpandProperties -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components" | select -ExpandProperty Properties | Select Name, InstrumentationKey
```

Comment: Using the new `Az` module, the command to list all instrumentation keys from all resource groups would be `Get-AzResource -ExpandProperties -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/components" | Select -ExpandProperty Properties | Select Name, InstrumentationKey`

Answer (score 1):

As far as obtaining the name of your App Insights instance using the Instrumentation Key via C#, I was able to cobble together the following program. The documentation for the Azure SDK is very hit-or-miss, and the NuGet packages are still in preview.

#### Install the NuGet Packages

```bsh
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights -IncludePrerelease
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication -IncludePrerelease
```

#### Retrieve App Insights Components

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights.Management;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights.Management.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Rest;

namespace CoreConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // NOTE - see below
            var auth = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

            const string url = "https://management.azure.com/";

            var token = await auth.GetAccessTokenAsync(url);

            var cred = new TokenCredentials(token);

            var client = new ApplicationInsightsManagementClient(cred)
            {
                SubscriptionId = "<your-subscription-id>",
            };

            var list = new List<ApplicationInsightsComponent>();

            var all = await client.Components.ListAsync();
            list.AddRange(all);

            foreach(var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.InstrumentationKey}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that you need to be using C# 7.1 or later to have an `async Task Main` in your console app).

**A Note on Authentication:** The `AzureServiceTokenProvider` constructor takes an optional connection string to authenticate with Azure. It worked without one for me since I had used `az login` via the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest). There are quite a few other ways to get credentials, some of which are discussed [in the Java client docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md).

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to query just the InstrumentationKey you want using an OData query, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make that work.

There is a more general `ResourceManagementClient` in the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager` package, which would let you do something like the following:

```
var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.ResourceManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = "<your-subscription-id>" };

var query = new ODataQuery<GenericResourceFilter>(o => o.ResourceType == "microsoft.insights/components")
{
    Filter = "", // filter by Instrumentation Key here?
    Expand = "$expand=Properties",
};

using (var resp = await client.Resources.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(query))
{
    foreach (var item in resp.Body)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance name is {item.Name}");
    }
}
```

Finally, [this project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-dotnet-manage-resource) has some other examples which may be useful.

Comment: In the above answer, the first snippet that uses Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights.Management package works.
Although, you have to set the following as connection string if you are planning to authenticate from within .NET code using a service principal (by default it looks for CLI auth and MSI and fails if neither are present) :  

$"RunAs=App;AppId={clientId};TenantId={tenantId};AppKey={clientSecret}";

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#use-a-shared-secret-credential-to-sign-into-azure-ad

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following C# program to get the application insights instance name given the instrumentation key. It doesn't require you to install any package. You just need to get the token first using the following commands provided you have Azure CLI installed.

```
az login
az account get-access-token --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And then replace the token in the below code in the first line of the main function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FindAppInsights;

class SubscriptionList
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}

class Subscription
{
    [JsonPropertyName("subscriptionId")]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

class AppInsightsList
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public List<AppInsights> AppInsights { get; set; }
}

class AppInsights
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("properties")]
    public AppInsightsProperties Properties { get; set; }
}

class AppInsightsProperties
{
    [JsonPropertyName("InstrumentationKey")]
    public string InstrumentationKey { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        string token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        Console.Write("Enter instrumentation key - ");
        string instrumentationKey = Console.ReadLine();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Uri baseUri = new Uri(@"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01");
        client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(baseUri);
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var listOfSubscriptions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SubscriptionList>(data) ?? new SubscriptionList();

        foreach (var subscription in listOfSubscriptions.Subscriptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Searching for instrumentation key {instrumentationKey} in subscription - {subscription.DisplayName}");
            HttpClient appInsightsClient = new HttpClient();
            var appInsightsUri = new Uri(@$"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription.SubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components?api-version=2015-05-01");
            appInsightsClient.BaseAddress = appInsightsUri;
            appInsightsClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            appInsightsClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await appInsightsClient.GetAsync(appInsightsUri);
            data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var appInsightsInstances = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppInsightsList>(data) ?? new AppInsightsList();
            var instance = appInsightsInstances.AppInsights.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Properties.InstrumentationKey, instrumentationKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (instance != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found app insights instance {instance.Name} with instrumentation key {instance.Properties.InstrumentationKey} in subscription {subscription.DisplayName}");                    
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"No app insights instance with instrumentation key - {instrumentationKey} found");
    }
}
```